# Is my password vulnerable to recovery using my Apple ID?

Tags: security, apple-id, password, system-settings

For some time, in Mavericks, I had an option, which I had disabled, in **Users & Groups > Password** to reset the password using Apple ID

[image]

This option vanished after a migration, under Mavericks, to a new machine

[image]

and remains absent after an update to Yosemite

[image]

So I can't tell: Can a I reset my password using my Apple ID or not?

---

I had explicitly disabled this earlier for security reasons, but now I can't tell whether it has been enabled or not (or how I'd change it if I wanted to).

Comment: Is the Apple ID set ?

Comment: @Buscar웃: I don't know. How would I find out? There's no control for setting it on **Users & Groups > Password**. I think it usually appears above the sections I've illustrated; but that area is blank for me.

Comment: Thanks, so that one is missing (to set the Apple ID!, lets do some research on it. Your Apple Store works ?

Comment: My Apple ID is fine and set for all other purposes as normal (calendar, mail, store, etc.). But setting it for *password recovery* is a different thing. There's no place to do that now (and no way to see whether it's set or not) that I can see.

Comment: @Buscar웃: Right, so that may be why the ability to change the settings gone (putting aside that the first example was also a FV2 system). But because the choice is gone, does that mean the *functionality* is too: does it mean (as I hope) I can't reset the password using the Apple ID (or just that I can't change whether I can)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is going on with missing reset password with Apple ID.

> FileVault 2-enabled Macs will not show a "Allow user to reset password
>   using Apple ID"

How to in FileVault is [described here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4790).

Since you are NOT using the Apple ID password recovery feature (it is not enabled) your FileVault password is NOT vulnerable to it. It can not be used on your system to recover your password.

Comment: That explains why the option to allow reset is gone. The question is whether the *functionality* is gone.

Comment: The functionality can (will) be restored if you disable the FileVault, it that is what you want.

Comment: No. The question is "Is my password vulnerable to recovery using my Apple ID?" That is: Is it *currently possible to use password recovery* given what I've described?

Comment: ring Apple & ask.